# Connect cylinders with a sphere in 3D

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm trying to connect cylinders with a sphere in 3D smoothly.

The sphere is given by a single 3d point-diameter data and the cylinders 
are given by point-diameter data as well for the start of the cylinder 
and the end of the cylinder for each cylinder respectively.

I would like to describe the cylinder by a spline,
and potentially the sphere also by a spline.

I'm not too familiar with computational geometry,
thus I wonder if this "algorithm" might be reasonable:

1. Create spline data for sphere
2. Create spline data for cylinders
3. Create the sphere and cylinders
4. Calculate intersection between the splines of the cylinder with the sphere
5. "Remesh". By this I mean use the intersections from the 4th step as the  new vertices for the cylinders and sphere.

Best wishes,
S.